# median of n number of integers from user

Tags: c

I can't seem to find the bug, help: I'm trying to input n, followed by n integers. Then output these n integers' median. n is odd and positive. n is less than 1 million.

**Sample Input**
5 37 28 21 44 49

**Sample Output**
37

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INTEGERS 6


int numbers[6];

int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(int*) a - *(int*) b);
}

int main() {
    int n, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("Enter numbers:");
        scanf("%d", numbers[i]);

    }

    qsort(numbers, INTEGERS, sizeof (int), compare);
    for (n = 0; n < INTEGERS; n++) {
        printf("%d ", numbers[n]);
    }
    printf("\n%d ", numbers[INTEGERS / 2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you expected to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: sample input
5 37 28 21 44 49
sample output
37

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scanf requires a memory address, not a value.

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INTEGERS 6


int numbers[INTEGERS];

int compare(const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(int*) a - *(int*) b);
}

int main() {
    int n, i;

    printf("Enter numbers:");
    for (i = 0; i < INTEGERS; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }

    qsort(numbers, INTEGERS, sizeof (int), compare);
    for (n = 0; n < INTEGERS; n++) {
        printf("%d ", numbers[n]);
    }
    printf("\n%d ", numbers[INTEGERS / 2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code a number like `6` in your program.  You have that constant `INTEGERS` and you should use it rather than putting the `6`.  I edited the above answer to make the array declaration use `INTEGERS` and to make the `for` loop use `INTEGERS`.

Comment: @steveha, Sure agreed. I was just answering the question as asked, using the code provided.